# Font on AE really difficult to read

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

**Is it just me, or is the Roboto font used on Android Enthusiasts really difficult to read? On my screen it looks like an XXX-lite variant.
The bold titles are fine, it is the "normal" text which is an issue.**

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: [It looks okay on my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoACl.png). What OS? What browser?

Comment: I literally came to Meta just to ask this question. I have all the Roboto fonts installed on my Windows 10 laptop, which are readable in Word. Chrome says the site is using Roboto, but it is way too thin.

Comment: Update: Just checked the linked question and can confirm that the font is fine in Firefox, Edge and IE. Very strange that the issue is in Chrome, given that it's a Google font.

Comment: Windows 10, Chrome, completely unreadable:  http://imgur.com/a/0MLxj

Comment: Also unreadable in Opera on Windows 10 (looks fine in Firefox)